# Tensor dot product with rank one tensor

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to compute an inner product between tensors in numpy.

I have a vector `x` of shape `(n,)` and a tensor `y` of shape `d*(n,)` with `d > 1` and would like to compute $\langle y, x^{\otimes d} \rangle$. That is, I want to compute the sum

$$\langle y, x^{\otimes d} \rangle= \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_d\in{1,\dots,n}}y[i_1, \dots, i_d]x[i_1]\dots x[i_d].$$

A working implementation I have uses a function to first compute $x^{\otimes d}$ and then uses `np.tensordot`:

```
def d_fold_tensor_product(x, d) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Compute d-fold tensor product of a vector.
    """
    assert d > 1, "Tensor order must be bigger than 1."

    xd = np.tensordot(x, x, axes=0)
    while d > 2:
        xd = np.tensordot(xd, x, axes=0)
        d -= 1

    return xd

n = 10
d = 4
x = np.random.random(n)
y = np.random.random(d * (n,))
result = np.tensordot(y, d_fold_tensor_product(x, d), axes=d)
```

Is there a more efficient and pythonic way? Perhaps without having to compute $x^{\otimes d}$.

Answer (score 0):

The math is hard to read, so I'm going to skip that.  Instead let's look at the sample calculation

```
In [168]: n = 10
     ...: d = 4
     ...: x = np.random.random(n)
     ...: y = np.random.random(d * (n,))
In [169]: x.shape
Out[169]: (10,)

In [171]: d_fold_tensor_product(x,d).shape
Out[171]: (10, 10, 10, 10)
In [172]: result = np.tensordot(y, d_fold_tensor_product(x, d), axes=d)

In [174]: result
Out[174]: array(384.20478955)
In [175]: y.shape
Out[175]: (10, 10, 10, 10)
```

`tensordot` can a be a complex call, though it all reduces to a call to `dot`.  I once dug through the action with a single `axis` value.  But without revisiting it that, or even looking at the docs (shame on me, I know :), this flattened `dot` does the same thing:

```
In [176]: np.dot(y.ravel(), d_fold_tensor_product(x, d).ravel())
Out[176]: 384.20478955316673
```

So the `d_fold...` has somehow expanded or replicated `x` to a 4d array.  Guess I'll have to digest that action :(

That function is doing repeated outer products:

```
In [177]: np.tensordot(x,x,axes=0).shape
Out[177]: (10, 10)
In [178]: np.allclose(np.tensordot(x,x,axes=0), x[:,None]*x)
Out[178]: True

In [181]: temp = d_fold_tensor_product(x,d)
In [182]: np.allclose(temp, x[:,None,None,None]*x[:,None,None]*x[:,None]*x)
Out[182]: True
```

or put all together:

```
In [184]: np.dot((x[:,None,None,None]*x[:,None,None]*x[:,None]*x).ravel(),y.ravel())
Out[184]: 384.20478955316673
```

So that eliminates the repeated `tensordot`, but isn't easily generalizable to other `d`.

Another way - still not generalizable, but may help visualize the task:

```
In [186]: np.einsum('ijkl,i,j,k,l',y,x,x,x,x)
Out[186]: 384.2047895531675
```

Some timings - your use of `tensordot` is slower than the most direct outer product:

```
In [193]: timeit temp = d_fold_tensor_product(x,d)
151 µs ± 127 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [194]: timeit x[:,None,None,None]*x[:,None,None]*x[:,None]*x
61.3 µs ± 1.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

A generalization of the outer product is in between:

```
In [195]: timeit np.multiply.reduce(np.array(np.ix_(x,x,x,x),object))
85.1 µs ± 57.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

A more general way of doing the repeated outer product:

```
def foo(x,d):
    x1 = np.expand_dims(x, tuple(range(1,d))) # make (10,1,1,1)
    res = x1
    for _ in range(1,d):
        x1 = x1[...,0]
        res = res*x1
    return res
In [219]: foo(x,d).shape
Out[219]: (10, 10, 10, 10)
```

times almost as good as the explicit version:

```
In [220]: timeit foo(x,d)
72.7 µs ± 47.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
In [221]: np.dot(foo(x,d).ravel(),y.ravel())
Out[221]: 384.20478955316673
```